# If I have a class in C# with properties as "private set", how can I still get object as a member of the class from a POST request?

Tags: c#, .net

For example, let's say I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Prop1 { get; private set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; private set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; private set; }

    public MyClass CreateFromRaw (MyClass thePostedObject)
    {
        MyClass newObj = new MyClass()
        {
            Prop1 = thePostedObject.Prop1,
            Prop2 = thePostedObject.Prop2,
            Prop3 = thePostedObject.Prop3
        };
    }

}
```

And I receive it in a POST request like this:

```
[Route("receive")]
        [HttpPost]
        public MyClass GetDocumentTemplateByDocTemplateId([FromBody]MyClass thePostedObject)
        {
            return MyClass.CreateFromRaw(thePostedObject);
        }
```

Since each prop in MyClass is a `private set`, they're not parsed out into a MyClass object from `thePostedObject`.  How would I keep the props as `private set`'s, while still being able to parse from a POST request? Would I need to create a new class with those props as NOT private set?

Comment: Why not use a specific model class for the controller and then map that to your MyClass through the constructor?

Comment: JSON deserialization can not set the value to properties which are not public set. You can create a new class with public properties, use it in the controller and have that class object passed to `MyClass` constructor.